# Comparing the elements of a list of strings

Tags: java, string, list, if-statement, linked-list

I am trying to compare the elements of a list I created from reading a file.

The list sizes vary from 3 up to 10 elements. I want to go over my elements in the list, compare their length (I tried doing that by `String  = s.length()`) it worked and I got the length of every element in the list.

How can I compare each element's length? I want to choose the closest 2 elements in length and determine their index.

For instance, if this is the input file:

```
ATGTCATGG
ATGCGATGGGGGTCGCCC
ATGTTT
```

the closest 2 strings are 3 apart in length, and their indices are 0 and 2.

```
public class ListTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PrintStream output = new PrintStream(System.out);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        output.print("Enter the name of the file ");
        String fileName = input.nextLine();
        Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        List<String> listo = new ArrayList<String>();
        String token = "";
        while ( fileInput.hasNext() ) {
            token = fileInput.next();
            listo.add(token);
        }
        fileInput.close();
        for ( int i =0; i < listo.size(); i++) {
            String components = listo.get(i);
            int lengtho = components.length();
            //output.println(lengtho);  
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your question the first time reading it :)

Comment: You'd probably be better off comparing the Levenshtein Edit Distance for each pair of strings if your actual goal is to get the closest matching strings. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance.

Answer (score 2):

If it's okay to change the line order, you could create a `Comparator` to sort by length

```
public class LengthComparator implements Comparator<String> {
  public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    return s1.length() - s2.length();
  }
}
```

Use Collections.sort to sort your list by length, then you can iterate through the sorted list compare each string to the next string, and see if that's shorter than the previous shortest

```
int shortestIdx = 0;
int shortestDist = Math.abs(list.get(0).length() - list.get(1).length());
for (int idx = 0; idx < list.size(); idx++) {
  //left this for you to fill in
}
```

Comment: Comparator implements compare(T obj1,T obj2) method

Comment: @ControlAltDel 
i tried this but i got an error .. int difference = 0; for ( int i =0; i < listo.size(); i++) { String components = listo.get(i); int lengtho = components.length(); difference = Math.abs(listo.get(i).length() - listo.get(i + 1).length()); } output.println(difference); i'm so lost.. –

Comment: what error? If you are so lost you really need to get more extensive help from your teacher rather than us here at StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your List using `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)` where you can define your own Comparator which compare Strings in your way.

Comment: and then you lose the index :P

Comment: Sorry, OP question is actually a bit harder then the first time I read it.

Comment: Ok, save sortList as tempList and then from non sorted list indexOf(Object o) :)))